# Difference between script filed and life cycle methods in Grapesjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grapesjs

I am new to Grapesjs, and i find the intro in Grapesjs doc website:

so if we have code like this:

```js
editor.BlockManager.add('test-block', {
  label: 'Test block',
  attributes: {class: 'fa fa-text'},
  content: {
    script: "alert('Hi'); console.log('the element', this)",
    // Add some style just to make the component visible
    style: {
      width: '100px',
      height: '100px',
      'background-color': 'red',
    }
  }
});
```

On the doc website it says:

> If you check now the generated HTML coded by the editor (via Export button or editor.getHtml()), you might see something like this:

```js
<div id="c764"></div>
<script>
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('#c764');
  for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function(){
      // START component code
      alert('Hi');
      console.log('the element', this)
      // END component code
    }.bind(items[i]))();
  }
</script>
```

It looks like all the stuff defined in script tag will be executed after the component mount, on the other way, considering Grapesjs provide `view.init()` and `view.onRender()` such life cycle methods, I was thinking we can probably achieve exactly the same effect using such life cycle methods.

So my question would be: what's difference between the `script` and component own life cycle methods?

BTW, I use React before, and i did most state initialization and data fetching in `componentDidMount()` such life cycle, so i personally could not get what could be the scenario for `script` in Grapesjs(Especially when i comparing those two libs.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you should know Grapes uses backbone.js, which is pretty different to react.

Now, talking about how it works for grapesjs.

- Lifecycle hooks will allow you to interact with model and editor instance during website building process.
- Script will contain javascript your component needs to be useful in and outside the editor (Obviously, having limited (read-only) access to model properties).

[Here](https://codepen.io/jvas28/pen/WNQyMJp?editors=1111) you can see a very basic, and probably dummy example of both cases.

1. Setting listener on init: You'll probably won't need to alert changes in component attributes in resulting page...
2. Add animation class: script will run when render in editor, but also will run at published page, so you can see the animation out of grapes' editor.

```
    const editor = grapesjs.init({
      height: "100%",
      container: "#gjs",
      showOffsets: true,
      fromElement: true,
      noticeOnUnload: false,
      storageManager: false,
      canvas: {
        styles: [
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css"
        ]
      }
    });
    editor.DomComponents.addType("MagicBox", {
      model: {
        defaults: {
          tagName: "div",
          attributes: {
            alert: ""
          },
          traits: ["alert"]
        },
        init() {
          this.listenTo(this, "change:attributes:alert", this.handleChange);
        },
        handleChange(a) {
          alert(this.get("attributes").alert);
        }
      }
    });

    const blockManager = editor.BlockManager;
    blockManager.add("magic-box", {
      label: "MagicBox",
      content: {
        type: "MagicBox",
        tagName: "div",
        style: {
          width: "100px",
          height: "100px",
          background: "blue"
        },
        script: 'this.className+="animate__animated animate__bounce"'
      },
      category: "Basic",
      attributes: {
        title: "Magic Box"
      }
    });
```